# Sending User Agent header through URLFetch API on GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm sending a request to my API like so:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,  'allow_self_signed' => true),
        'http' => array('method' => 'GET', 'header'  => "Authorization:Basic " . base64_encode($token.':'))
    )
);
$resp = file_get_contents('https://api.site.com/test', false, $context);

if(!preg_match("/200 OK/", $http_response_header[0]))   http_response_code(400);
else                                                    echo $resp;
```

However, I am trying to let `api.site.com` to know what my `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is that's making the request.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `User-Agent` header along side your `Authorization:Basic` in the stream context options under the `http` key. See http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php for details

Edit: [Google App engine information](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/)

Headers identifying request source

> The following headers indicate the app ID of the requesting app:
>
> - User-Agent. This header can be modified but App Engine will append an identifier string to allow servers to identify App Engine requests. The appended string has the format "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: APPID)", where APPID is your app's identifier.
> - X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid. This header cannot be modified, and is added automatically if the request is sent via the URL Fetch service when the follow redirects parameter is set to False.

Comment: `This value will only be used if user-agent is not specified in the header context option above.` - So I'm using Google App Engine and it is sending a user agent header, just not the user agent of the person sending the request, rather the server that's sending the GET

Comment: That is another story. App Engine's URLFetch service strips user-agent. You cannot override that unfortunately.

Comment: So there is **no** way to send the information I need?

Comment: I edited the answer with more details so the answer is yes and no. Or yes but they will append their own data.

Comment: I believe if you use curl extension, you should be able to set custom user-agent header.